# What is the correct way of initialising variables when using typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Our company started using Pythons Typing since its made available in the newer Python3 versions.
We are using the "mypy" linter to help with typing errors in our scripts.
My problem occurs when im initialising empty variables at the script header, for example like this:

```
VARIABLE_NAME: str = None
```

Since it will get set later, my current knowledge is that you should initialise these variables with `None`.

mypy sees this as incorrect and shows the following error:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "str")mypy(error)
```

Now im wondering.
Should I instead initialise the variable with an empty string?
Im not sure whats the best practice here.

Comment: Why are you initialising with None? You should just initialise when the variable is actually going to be assigned to.

Comment: Its common practices here in this company to Initialise global variables, like ConfigParsers, near the beginning of the script.

Comment: If you're going to use a string, you could initialise it as `""`; an empty string.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about doing that, but this doesnt really work well with complex datatypes like datetimes for example, so I was wondering if thats the correct way of handling this. The answer below from @monkut seems to be the right way of doing this.

Comment: I've voted to reopen because this "correct way of initialising" is clearly different from the supposed duplicate "correct hint for none". The latter is one possible answer, another answer (that I'm unable to provide because it's closed) is that if `None` is never actually the true value, then you should hint without initialising: `var: str` and only later assign `var = "whatever"`. Whether the duplicate is appropriate at all depends on intentions not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected type 'MyObject', got 'None' instead in \_\_init\_\_ with type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493904/expected-type-myobject-got-none-instead-in-init-with-type-hints)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this would be written as:

```py
from typing import Optional

VARIABLE_NAME: Optional[str] = None
```

Comment: This seems to be the right way, thanks a lot! Didnt know about ```Optional```