# Expected type 'MyObject', got 'None' instead in __init__ with type hints

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

When initializing an instance variable, I like to include a type hint.  However, sometimes I'm not ready to assign any particular value to it, I'd like it to start out as "None".

```
self._active_cal_fluid: MyObject = None
```

This leads to PyCharm giving me an inspection error:
`Expected type 'MyObject', got 'None' instead`

I can't create an "empty" version of `MyObject()` because that makes no sense in my context.
If I wait to initialize it later in some other method, it complains that I initialize an instance variable outside of **init**() and typehints don't work.

I'd prefer to leave typehints enabled.
I don't want to disable this inspection in general, I just want to get rid of this particular warning **only** when an object is initialized to "None".  Is such a thing possible in PyCharm?

Comment: That makes sense, None *isn't* MyObject. Did you try https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional?

Comment: @jonrsharpe:  It certainly makes sense, and your suggestion fixed it.  Thank you.  Would you like to post it as answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the type annotation is simply wrong.
in Your case, `self._active_cal_fluid` can have two types:

type MyObject and type None

this can be written as : `Union[None, MyObject]` or `Optional[MyObject]`

here the full annotation

```
from typing import Optional

...
# definition of MyObject
...

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._active_cal_fluid: Optional[MyObject] = None
```

if "MyObject" is not defined at the time of the Class Definition, You need to use "forward Annotation" and put the type into quotes:

```
from typing import Optional

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._active_cal_fluid: Optional["MyObject"] = None

...
# definition of MyObject
...
```